# How to compute $\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\sin^a{\pi x}}{(1-x)^a} , a \in \Re$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I'm trying to compute this limit:

$$ \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\sin^a{\pi x}}{(1-x)^a} , a \in \Re $$

It should be quite easy, however, I just can't see it now... if it would be without $a$, it would be very easy with using l'Hospital rule. However, it isn't possible to do in this situation.

I think that it would help if I expressed $\sin{\pi x}$ with using the cosine function somehow. However, as I've said, I can't see it, and maybe this is not a good idea...

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Is your concern that $\sin \pi x$ takes on negative values for $x > 1$ and $x - 1$ is small, so that $\sin^a\pi x$ is not defined if $a = -2$ say? If so, I share your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y=1-x$. We then have
$$\dfrac{\sin^a(\pi x)}{(1-x)^a} = \dfrac{\sin^a(\pi -\pi y)}{y^a}=\dfrac{\sin^a(\pi y)}{y^a}$$
Hence, the limit as $x \to 1$, is same as $y \to 0$, which is nothing but $\pi^a$.

Comment: Oh, thanks! As I've supposed, it's easy, however, I was still looking on it without getting a good idea. This helped me, thank you!

Comment: The function in the limit isn't defined as a real one in many cases. Read comment below the question.

Comment: @Timbuc It doesn't matter. For instance, $\lim_{x \to 0^-} \sqrt{\sin(x)}/\sqrt{x}=1$ assuming you take the principal value.

Comment: @user17762 You're using terms from complex analysis and advanced stuff . The question's tagged as "limits" and without l'Hospital.  The example you give is of a non-real function. It didn't look like the OP wanted this.

Answer (score 0):

Hints: $\sin \pi x $ ~ $\pi x$ when $x\to 1$

Comment: For $x\to 1$, $\pi x\to \pi$ and $\sin\pi x\to 0$